# converting 2019-01-01:01 string into date time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Hello I have  a string  where date are concatenated with hour "2019-01-01:01" in panda data frame column.  I want to convert it as date time format like bellow

2019-01-01 01:00:00

I have tried 
`pd.to_datetime(data_frame_trainbase['date_TRXHOUR'])` but giving me the  error

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2019-01-01:01')
I think the string presentation is wrong here but didn't find a solution . kindly help me
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the format

```
pd.to_datetime(data_frame_trainbase['date_TRXHOUR'], format='%Y-%m-%d:%H')
```

Comment: thanks it worked but  could I convert it  2019-01-01 01:00:00 into this format

Comment: @Kalyan data_frame_trainbase['date_TRXHOUR'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d:%H'), make sure date_TRXHOUR already daytime format

Comment: ye @YOBEN_S I got that the type is date time  but  if I get that   2019-01-01 01:00:00  I could get some benefits in slicing  :)